# How to configure Apache for Vue Router in history mode used in Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, apache, vue-router, single-page-application

I have a Vue application as a WP plugin, and currently I am migrating it to SPA using Vue router, history mode is used in Vue router, so I will need a redirect from Apache for every route that doesnt exists anymore. What is the way of doing this without reload if user types url in browser and how to redirect that request that to do routing on frontend side without killing current vue instance and reloading whole page, is that even possible with wordpress. Thanks in advance!

I was trying some virtual host configuration and setting fallback resource but without any success.

Comment: You definitely need to catch entry routes (ie user-types-url-in-browser), but doesn't the plugin or WordPress, provide this ability? Anyways, my recommendation is to keep WordPress as a headless CMS, and make your main app a fresh Vue install using nodejs,  which means a 100% Javascript environment, which means a single source of truth for routes (one global routes definition). Even better... just use Nuxt.js. WordPress will simply be your CMS backend.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Thanks for the reply, definitely agree with you about full js env, but that is currently big refactor according to the time I have, but if frontend side routing using history mode to work with html history api, doesnt we need to adjust server conf to redirect to the html that our app exists in no matter what env we have on fe side, request is request?

Comment: Yes, in your particular context ultimately you will have two places where you must define-and-manage routes: the VueRouter object and whatever is handling entry routes (ie the backend framework, WordPress?). In one monolith Laravel project, we have VueRouter and Laravel's routes file, and I never touched the server (nginx). With WordPress, I would presume that somewhere you can define entry routes. It seems silly that you'd have to manage things in server config given the deep layers in the stack.